# How to randomly access contents of a blob in JavaScript without loading in the whole buffer first?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a binary file editor similar to https://hexed.it/. I want the app to be able to handle large files (multiple gigabytes) without long wait times.

The inital code for opening a file (blob) from the user:

```
const domFile = input?.files?.[0];
if (!domFile){
    return;
}
const name = domFile.name;
const buffer = await domFile.arrayBuffer();
const file: File = {
    name,
    buffer
}
state.files.push(file);
state.currentFile = file;
```

The problematic line was this:

```
const buffer = await domFile.arrayBuffer();
```

The issue is, the UI will only update after the entire file has been loaded even though I'm not rendering the entire file.

The renderer only renders 50 rows in the dom at any given time. This means I only need 50*16=800 bytes from the buffer to render a specific section of the file. This 50 line segment will be referred to as 'window' form now on.

Once the entire buffer has been loaded I can do random access on it and render the current window, which works great.

However when opening files as large as 7 GB the program pauses for about a minute to read the whole buffer and this is not ideal.

Current solution:

```
const domFile = input?.files?.[0];
if (!domFile){
    return;
}
const name = domFile.name;
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(domFile.size);
const file: File = {
    name,
    buffer
}
state.files.push(file);
state.currentFile = file;

const queuingStrategy = new CountQueuingStrategy({ highWaterMark: 1024 });
let bytesWritten = 0;
const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
const writableStream = new WritableStream(
    {
        write(chunk) {
            console.log(bytesWritten,chunk);
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
                    view.set(chunk,bytesWritten);
                    bytesWritten+=chunk.length;
                    resolve();
                })
            });
        },
        close() {
            console.log("done");
        },
        abort(err) {
            console.error("Sink error:", err);
        },
    },
    queuingStrategy,
);
    
domFile.stream().pipeTo(writableStream);
```

With the streams API I was able to open a file in the viewer without waiting for all bytes to be read. This is slightly better as I don't have to wait one minute to render the start of the file, but if I want to view the end of the file I still have to wait for the entire file to be loaded, because this loads **all bytes** in a **sequential** way, instead of randomly accessing only the bytes needed at the time.

On hexedit I'm able it open the same file and scroll to the end without waiting for the whole file to be loaded. Sadly hexedit is not open source so I don't know how they implemented this.

TLDR: How do I randomly access a window of 800 bytes from a blob without first loading the whole file into an ArrayBuffer.